# ActivateItemAsync in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, .net, frontend, frameworks, caliburn.micro

I recently started studying about MVVM, in which I'm now looking at the Caliburn.Micro framework. Unfortunately I could only see very old content and the framework documentation is outdated. I'm using Caliburn 4.0.173, which no longer has the ActivateItem method that was replaced by ActivateItemAsync, follow the code below: ShellViewModel.cs.

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
        public async void LoadPageOne()
        {
            await ActivateItemAsync(new FirstChildViewModel(), CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public async void LoadPageTwo()
        {
            await ActivateItemAsync(new SecondChildViewModel(), CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

**ShellView.Xaml**

```
        <!-- Row 5 -->
        <Button x:Name="LoadPageOne" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"> Load First Page</Button>
        <Button x:Name="LoadPageTwo" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"> Load Second Page</Button>

        <!-- Row 6 -->
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
```

In the video he is using dotnet framework 4.6 and caliburn in 3.2, while I am using dotnet 6. Even adding everything I tried to find, even on github, the usercontrol screen does not change. Could someone tell me where I'm letting it go? I'm a junior programmer and I wanted to understand about this problem, instead of having to change everything to a previous version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works.

If you want to use built in IoC and want to add messaging between view models you can check out [my sample project](https://github.com/EgemenCiftci/caliburn-micro-demo).

ViewModels:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CaliburnMicroDemo.ViewModels;

public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>
{
    public async Task LoadPageOneAsync()
    {
        await ActivateItemAsync(new FirstChildViewModel());
    }

    public async Task LoadPageTwoAsync()
    {
        await ActivateItemAsync(new SecondChildViewModel());
    }
}

public class FirstChildViewModel : Screen
{
}

public class SecondChildViewModel : Screen
{
}
```

ShellView.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CaliburnMicroDemo.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Shell Window" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button x:Name="LoadPageOneAsync" Content="Load First Page" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="LoadPageTwoAsync" Content="Load Second Page" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

FirstChildView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnMicroDemo.Views.FirstChildView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

SecondChildView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnMicroDemo.Views.SecondChildView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```